# Replacing input type="color" with an icon

Tags: html, css, input

I have a question. I'm creating a Paint App with canvas and in controls I have an input type="color" to let the users choose from all colors, but the default styles are quite bad for me, so I decided to replace it with fa fa-palette icon, but I didn't think of any possible solution. Any thoughts how to achieve this? Thanks.

```
<aside id="choose-color">
    <input id="create-color" type="color">
    <!--and more-->
</aside>

<style>
      #create-color {
          border-radius: 100%;
          height: 60px;
          width: 60px;
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          /*here I would like something like - background-image: url(".fa fa-palette") (I already tried background-image, but it didn't work with inputs)*/
      }
</style>
```

EDIT: Ok, so I figured it out, all I needed to do was just to wrap the input in label, add the icon in the label and hide the input, like that:

```
<label for="create-color">
      <i class="fa fa-palette"></i>
      <input type="color" id="create-color" style="display: none">
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as using a `<label>` and hiding the `<input>`, I would add `list='xx'` to your `<input>` to include a preset list (pointing to a `<datalist>` that shows your preferred colors)

```
 <input type="color" 
  id="create-color" 
  style="display: none" 
  list='mycolors'
  onChange='this.previousElementSibling.style.color=this.value'>


 <datalist id="mycolors">
    <option>#FF0000</option>
    <option>#00FF00</option>
    <option>#0000FF</option>
 </datalist>
```

See jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/bv1fod6j/12/ for working example which starts with the list options but allows you to jump to a color selector (as shown below from a Windows environment):

[image]

You can then use some additional js to manage the datalist (adding and removing colors as required)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you can get it.

```css
button{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
button:focus {
  outline-style: none; 
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button><i class='fas fa-palette'></i></button>
</body>
```